# Unsure why my javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am getting some errors with this code. Apparently split is not a function. I am also getting this error:

GET http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico 404 (File not found)

Basically what I am trying to do is convert a csv to a 2D array through which I loop and do some analysis. I'm not great with javascript so please don't crucify me lol. But please feel free to point out any other issues I really need this to work!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>


    <script>
    
    
    d3.csv('enrollment.csv', function(data) {
    
    
    function csvToArray(csv) {
          rows = csv.split("\n");
    
          return rows.map(function (row) {
            return row.split(",");
          });
    };
    
    
    let count = 0;
    
    let enroll = csvToArray(data);
    
    console.log(enroll);
    
    let dup_Tracker = [];
    
    for (i = 1; i < enroll.length; i++) {
      if (enroll[i][1] === enroll[i-1][1]) {
        if (enroll[i][0] !== enroll[i-1][0]) {
          dup_Tracker.push(enroll[i]);
        }
      } else {
          count += 1;
      }
    }
    
    });
    
    // console.log(dup_Tracker);
    
    
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you share the all the errors you are getting? The one you mentioned in your post is related to the favicon not being found where you referenced it. Also, is the .csv file you are referencing found in the same place as this html file?

Comment: yes! the csv should be in the right place and I dont believe im referencing a favicon anywhere so im not sure why that is happening. This is the error: GET http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico 404 (File not found)

Comment: The favicon error you got is because there is not a `favicon.ico` image but is not related to your code, please share about the split but at first look seems like something is wrong with your loaded rows